# Do I need to re-vaccinate my dog for rabies after possible exposure to an infected animal?

Tags: dogs, vaccination

I brought a traumatized little pup who had been bitten by an aggressive dog, seven days ago. The aggressive dog died, convulsing, the day after biting. The dog didn't show lack of coordination, jaw paralysis or salivation, though. Some people of the locality say he was killed by people due to aggressiveness, when he was hit on the head and he suffered a concussion. But no one will ever know what killed the dog actually.

The pup is receiving rabies post exposure prophylaxis. She is on day 5 and is quite active and healthy as of now. Her mother was never vaccinated so no maternal rabies antibody in her.

Now, we have an adult dog in our home. He is vaccinated every year for rabies. His rabies vaccination is due in March. He plays with the pup and licks her. Do we need to re-vaccinate the adult dog right now, or will he be protected adequately?

I asked three vets. One said we need to administer full 5 course post exposure prophylaxis to the adult dog. But two other said we need not administer anything. I am confused. Could you please help?

Answer (score 3):

From https://www.cdc.gov/rabies/specific_groups/veterinarians/potential_exposure.html

"Dogs, cats, and ferrets that are currently vaccinated with a USDA-licensed rabies vaccine should be revaccinated immediately, kept under the owner’s control, and observed for 45 days. If the animal under observation develops any signs of illness, it should be evaluated by a veterinarian. Any illness in an animal under observation should be reported immediately to the local health department. If the animal under observation develops signs suggestive of rabies, it should be euthanized by an animal health professional and its head submitted to a diagnostic laboratory for testing."

Regardless, since you have had one vet who said yes, I would listen to him, because rabies is for all practical purposes one hundred percent fatal in humans, and highly fatal in dogs, and so all precautions should be taken when there is a chance of exposure.

Comment: Thank you! Do I need to administer him full 0 3 7 14 28 prophylaxis or just one vaccine as a booster is enough?

Comment: I would ask the one vet who said you should do a vaccination what type you should do.